# What does "Customer Notification Not Applicable " in Magento Order?

Tags: magento-1.8, orders

In the Magento Admin Panel, after a successful order under the Comments History tab I am getting the "Customer Notification Not Applicable" notice.

After this Magento will not send any order cancellation emails to customer.

My question is:

What does "Customer Notification Not Applicable" mean and why does Magento refuse to send out the order cancellation email to customer?

Comment: I would also like an answer to this!

Answer (score 3):

This just means that the customer isn't informed by e-mail, so the order e-mail isn't sent to the customer.

When you cancel orders, customers will not be notified by default.

If you want to inform your customers about the cancellation just use the "Comments history" section, add a message and check the box: *Notify the customer by e-mail*

The customer will be informed with the information you've just supplied.

Comment: If customer is not notify by email magento comment will be "Not Notified" but here is he get different message "Notification Not Applicable" may be both are different